# Groupby multiindex AND get sum for first index

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have data that I want to groupby and sum along a multi-index, but then also have the sum of just the first part of the multi-index. So the idea would be the index would be the multiindex, and then I could see both the size of that and the size of just its first group. So for example I have a dataframe like:

```
d = {'attr_1': ['A','A','A','B','B'], 'attr_2': ['a','a','b','a','b'],'val': [1,2,3,4,5]}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
df

    a_1 a_2 val
0   A   a   1
1   A   a   2
2   A   b   3
3   B   a   4
4   B   b   5
```

What I would like to make is:

```
        val sum_a1
a_1 a_2 
A   a   3   6
A   b   3   6
B   a   4   9
B   b   5   9
```

I'm looking for a way to do this cleanly. My current approach is to make a new dataframe, turn it into a dictionary, reset the index, and map the dictionary, but it seems like there should be an easier and more pythonic way to do this.

```
a = df.groupby(['a_1','a_2']).sum()
b = df.groupby(['a_1']).sum()
my_dict = b.to_dict()['val']
a = a.reset_index()
a['sum_a1'] = a.a_1.map(my_dict)
a
    a_1 a_2 val sum_a1
0   A   a   3   6
1   A   b   3   6
2   B   a   4   9
3   B   b   5   9
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Apologies if this is a repeated question I searched and couldn't find anything that was quite the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for `transform`

```
a = df.groupby(['attr_1','attr_2']).sum()
a['sum_a1']=a.groupby(level=0)['val'].transform('sum')
a
Out[14]: 
               val  sum_a1
attr_1 attr_2             
A      a         3       6
       b         3       6
B      a         4       9
       b         5       9
```

Answer (score 1):

With `set_index` and `sum` letting `join` align the indices.

```
df.set_index(['attr_1', 'attr_2']).pipe(
    lambda d: d.sum(level=[0, 1]).join(d.val.rename('sum_a1').sum(level=0))
)

               val  sum_a1
attr_1 attr_2             
A      a         3       6
       b         3       6
B      a         4       9
       b         5       9
```